# How to display Codecov.io badge in GitHub README.md?

Tags: html, github, markdown, code-coverage, badge

As mentioned in the title, how can I add a Codecov.io badge resembling the coverage of my project?

There is nothing stated about this in the [Docs](https://docs.codecov.io/docs) from Codecov.io.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a long search and Try-n-Error i was able to find something which [implicitly](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boennemann/badges/master/README.md) helped finding it out.

The way to implement a Codecov.io badge with your current Coverage ist the following :

In HTML :

```
<a href="https://codecov.io/github/<Your Organization/Acc.>/
<YourRepo>?branch=master">
<img alt="Coverage" src="https://codecov.io
/github/<Your Organization/Acc.>/<YourRepo>/coverage.svg?branch=master">
</a>
```

In Markdown:

```
[![codecov.io](https://codecov.io/github/<Your Organization/Acc.>/<YourRepo>/coverage.svg?branch=master)]
(https://codecov.io/github/<Your Organization/Acc.>/<YourRepo>?branch=master)
```

This Solution expects that you host the project on Github and that you upload the coverage reports.

Comment: This solution is very helpful for people who contribute the code but are not the owner of the repo. Other solutions above only work for those who are owners of the repo.

Answer (score 35):

Go to `https://codecov.io/gh/<your-organisation>/<your-project>/settings/badge`, here you can see your badges ready to be copied.

Or just navigate to your project and go to `Settings -> Badge`.

Answer (score 18):

Step-by-step guide to get your Codecov.io badge:

1. Go to **Settings** section

[image: Settings]

2. Click **Badge** section

[image: Badge]

3. Click **Copy** under **Markdown** section

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to https://app.codecov.io/gh/your_organization/your_repository/settings/badge (replace the placeholders in the link) and copy the code they show you there (there's HTML, markdown and RST). You need to get it from there because there's a unique access token for it.

Comment: The token is only necessary for private repos, AFAIK